# NullPointerException on a matrix of object

Tags: java, matrix, nullpointerexception

I know the answer may be stupid, but I can't find the solution.
I am tring to use a matrix of object like this

```
//static declaration (class attribute)
static Litteral [] [] explicitsPropagations;
...
//initialisation (sat and csp are declared)
explicitsPropagations = new Litteral[csp.nbVar()][sat.nbVar()*2];
...
//affectation (NullPointerException), idClause, iEP, iX are correctly declared

for (int i = 0 ; i < iX ; i++)
    explicitsPropagations[idClause][iEP[idClause]] = X[i];
```

Can someone see the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Without the error it is more difficult to help you... can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: Which **line** does the NPE occur on?

Comment: In addition to the comments above: what is inside csp.nbVar() and sat.nbVar()? What is iEP?  what is X? Your code is quite unclear at the moment.

Comment: Please see the guide [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to increase your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to 'find' your problem.  Change your code to this, and then post the error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < iX; i++) {
  int value = X[i];
  int index1 = idClause
  int index2 = iEP[idClause]
  explicitsPropagations[index1][index2] = value;
}
```

Comment: It would probably be more helpful if the answer would be written in Java instead of JavaScript.

Comment: It would be helpful if SO gave us a java editor too :)